# Firebase Messaging Service Not triggering activity

Tags: java, android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my app, I am facing few issues with triggering activity when I m sending notification on Vivo Mobiles. When I do this with app just launched few mins back, it works perfectly, whereas after some time it stops working and all notification went unattended.

Can u suggest some solution to do. Code is working fine for most of devices even when app is in foreground or background.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Vivo devices have a non-standard behavior for push-notifications.
see: http://www.vivoglobal.com/bbs/showthread.php?tid=98281

In particular try to enable your app in the `"Autostart manager"` setting screen